# set multiple states, and push to state of array in one onClick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm running into a recurring issue in my code where I want to grab multiple pieces of data from a component to set as states, and push those into an array which is having its own state updated. The way I am doing it currently isn't working and I think it's because I do not understand the order of the way things happen in js and react.

Here's an example of something I'm doing that doesn't work: [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/b2ofy6qa/) or code below.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            categoryTitle: null,
            categorySubtitle: null,
            categoryArray: [],
        }
    }

    pushToCategoryArray = () => {
        this.state.categoryArray.push({
            'categoryTitle': this.state.categoryTitle,
            'categorySubtitle': this.state.categorySubtitle,
        })
    }

    setCategoryStates = (categoryTitle, categorySubtitle) => {
        this.setState({
            categoryTitle: categoryTitle,
            categorySubtitle: categorySubtitle,
        })
        this.pushToCategoryArray();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <CategoryComponent
                setCategoryStates={this.setCategoryStates}
                categoryTitle={'Category Title Text'}
                categorySubtitle={'Category Subtitle Text'}
            />
        );
    }
}

class CategoryComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        var categoryTitle = this.props.categoryTitle;
        var categorySubtitle = this.props.categorySubtitle;
        return (
            <div onClick={() => (this.props.setCategoryStates(
                    categoryTitle,
                    categorySubtitle,
                ))}
            >
                <h1>{categoryTitle}</h1>
                <h2>{categorySubtitle}</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I can see in the console that I am grabbing the `categoryTitle` and `categorySubtitle` that I want, but they get pushed as `null` into `this.state.categoryArray`. Is this a scenario where I need to be using promises? Taking another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because setState is asynchronous (https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly).

Here's the problem

```
    //State has categoryTitle as null and categorySubtitle as null.
    this.state = {
        categoryTitle: null,
        categorySubtitle: null,
        categoryArray: [],
    }

//This gets the correct values in the parameters
setCategoryStates = (categoryTitle, categorySubtitle) => {
    //This is correct, you're setting state BUT this is not sync
    this.setState({
        categoryTitle: categoryTitle,
        categorySubtitle: categorySubtitle,
    })
    this.pushToCategoryArray();
}

//This method is using the state, which as can be seen from the constructor is null and hence you're pushing null into your array.
pushToCategoryArray = () => {
    this.state.categoryArray.push({
        'categoryTitle': this.state.categoryTitle,
        'categorySubtitle': this.state.categorySubtitle,
    })
}
```

Solution to your problem: pass callback to setState

```
setCategoryStates = (categoryTitle, categorySubtitle) => {
    //This is correct, you're setting state BUT this is not sync
    this.setState({
        categoryTitle: categoryTitle,
        categorySubtitle: categorySubtitle,
    }, () => {
       /*
          Add state to the array
          This callback will be called once the async state update has succeeded
          So accessing state in this variable will be correct.
       */
       this.pushToCategoryArray()
    })
}
```

and change

```
pushToCategoryArray = () => {
    //You don't need state, you can simply make these regular JavaScript variables
    this.categoryArray.push({
        'categoryTitle': this.state.categoryTitle,
        'categorySubtitle': this.state.categorySubtitle,
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think React doesn't re-render because of the pushToCategoryArray that directly change state. Need to assign new array in this.setState function.

```
// this.state.categoryArray.push({...})

const prevCategoryArray = this.state.categoryArray
this.setState({
    categoryArray: [ newObject, ...prevCategoryArray],        
)}
```